# Arithmetic expression expressed as tree

Tags: scheme, racket

Imagine an arithmetic expression such as (+ 1 (* 2 (- 3 5))) being thought of as a tree-like structure with numbers at the leaves and operator symbols at the interior nodes like below:

```
     +
   /   \
  1     *
       /  \
      2    -
          /  \
         3    5
```

each node can be expressed by a three element list: `(left-operand operator right-operand)`

I am trying to write a function
`(make-expr left-op operator right-op)`

that produces
`(left-op operator right-op)`

for example:
`(make-expr '(6 * 3) '+ '(5 -2)) => ((6 * 3) + (5 - 2))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> (list '(6 * 3) '+ '(5 - 2))
((6 * 3) + (5 - 2)
```

Yes, it's as simple as using the `list` function.